# Gnome-shell crashes because of Wayland

Tags: gnome, xorg, wayland

Recently I receive an error report whenever I boot Ubuntu. The message I receive is: Shell Journal Message in report.

[image: ShellJournal message in report]

It lets me know why Wayland doesn't start.

[image: /tmp/.X11-unix folder]

I tried to start Xwayland with su in console mode, then Xwayland gives the error.

```
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
(EE)
```

So I did like this;

```
$ echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
/run/user/1000
$ ls /run/user/1000
GPaste        bus     gdm                        gvfs        pipewire-0.lock                 snapd-session-agent.socket
ICEauthority  dbus-1  gnome-session-leader-fifo  gvfsd       pk-debconf-socket               systemd
app           dconf   gnome-shell                keyring     pulse                           update-notifier.pid
at-spi        doc     gnupg                      pipewire-0  snap.snapd-desktop-integration
```

XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is already set.

Although I reinstalled wayland, It does't work.
Nevertheless, X11 works well.

How can I get this working correctly?